# Easy-autocomplete doesn't display any suggestions, but no errors either

Tags: javascript, jquery, easyautocomplete

this is my code, which uses easy-autcomplete component.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="easy-autocomplete.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.easy-autocomplete.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="provider-json" v-model="adress" placeholder="Podaj adres:" type='text' class="form-control">
</body>
<script>
    var options = {
        url: "baza.json",

        getValue: "ulica",

        list: {
            match: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    };

    $("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
</html>
```

According to info on the site http://easyautocomplete.com/guide
this should be enough to work. It doesn't display any suggestions, but I see no errors in the console either. It looks to me like something in the css file doesn't work properly, but it's just my suspicion. Any suggestions? It's a snippet of my json.

```
{
"features": [
{
  "kod": "01-211", 
  "numer": "18/20", 
  "ulica": "ulica Marcina Kasprzaka"
}, 
{
  "kod": "01-211", 
  "numer": "24", 
  "ulica": "ulica Marcina Kasprzaka"
}, 
{
  "kod": "01-224", 
  "numer": "25A", 
  "ulica": "ulica Marcina Kasprzaka"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Could you also include a small snippet of the contents inside `baza.json` ? If there is no error in the console, maybe something is wrong with the data you use for the auto-suggest.

Comment: i think url i.e (baza.json) is incorrect, try copy this file in a folder and update the url value.

Comment: I've updated the code with .json file.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ... // your code
})
```

Comment: Something has changed, because the style of the input looks different. Still no suggestion, though.

Comment: according your json file you should add option
 listLocation: "features",